# How to listen to route changes in react router v5?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to throw out a warning when I try to go to another page or endpoint if the document is not saved

Comment: can you show the code you have tried ??

Comment: I haven't tried yet, I need to know how to subscribe to history changes in the react router v5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a declarative approach of how one can prevent navigation using `<Prompt>` component.

```
<Prompt
  when={isBlocking}
  message={location =>
    `Are you sure you want to go to ${location.pathname}`
  }
/>
```

`isBlocking` usually comes from the state of a component that needs to be conditionally rendered.

You can see a working example [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/preventing-transitions).